# How to get the rectangular coordinates of the annotation using ice pdf viewer

Tags: java, pdf, icepdf

I need to get the rectangular coordinates of the annotation using ice pdf viewer. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to go into the Viewer RI source code make a few changes and then rebuild the icepdf-viewer.jar.

The class org.icepdf.ri.common.tools.SquareAnnotationHandler handles all the mouse events and drawing for creating a Square annotation. This is a good place to start for extending or using it as a reference.

Add a message dialog to under mouseReleased

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rectangle coordinates x ---> "+rectToDraw.x+" y --> "+ rectToDraw.y+" Width --> "+ rectToDraw.width+" height --> "+ rectToDraw.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for answer.

Icepdf's Annotation class holds these coordinates. They can be retrieved like this:

```
     Rectangle2D.Float box = annotation.getUserSpaceRectangle();
     Map<String, Double> bounds = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        bounds.put("height", box.getHeight());
        bounds.put("width", box.getWidth());
        bounds.put("x", box.getX());
        bounds.put("y", box.getY());
```